# Как в андроид работать с онлайн базой данных MySQL?

Tags: android, php, java, mysql

Суть вопроса как в заголовке. Нужна информация, много информации! 
Есть БД расположенная на серваке, мне необходиммо подключится к ней с андроид приложения с возможностью чтения и записи! Знаю как это делать на PHP. А как с андроида получить доступ к БД ничего путного не нашел! В голову приходит только одно, написать свое АПИ и по нему через PHP работать с БД, а можно ли это сделать напрямую?

Comment: таки придется api писать )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напрямую можно, но крайне нежелательно, ведь user credentials придётся хранить в приложении. Так что, фактически, вариант у вас один — пишите апи.

Comment: А вот товарищи сверху пишут про форматы BSON и т.д.! Я на андроид работал только с XML и JSON т.к. есть стандартные библиотеки для работы с этими форматами. А как быть с ними если я захочу перейти на них?